# Return URL from PayPal takes too long and people close the window. I don't get the info back

Tags: url, return, delay, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal's PDT and IPN prototcols to create an interactive shopping cart.  Everything works really well.

The only glitch I am running into is that some customers do not wait for the PayPal page to return back to my website and terminate the window.  This prevents me from acquiring the transaction key so I can then query the IPN and get all the purchase information back.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to save the return data from the IPN response, which happens after the customer has pressed buy.

Pass the posted variable to local variables then save to database. For example $txn_id = $_GET["txn_id"];

Comment: You are not able to GET the txn_id if customer close the page before paypal return back to the site. I have the same issue that some customer close the page directly after payment before the redirect.